# How to change the dropdown default text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm trying to change the title of the dropdown. I'm using this [Multi-select plugin](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect).

But I was unable to change the text (Dropdown title) of the dropdown dynamically from JavaScript.

```
$('#pickere-buttonTitle').multiselect({
    buttonText: function(options, select) {
        return dist;
    }
});
```

Method 2

```
$('#pickere option:selected').value = state;
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="form-group">
                           <label>Select District:</label>
                           <select class="form-control" id="district-pickere">
                           </select>
                           </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                           <label>Select Sub District:</label>
                           <select class="form-control" id="subdistrict-pickere">
                           </select>
                           </div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
function editUser(id, name, mob, mail, addr, state, dist, subdist, type, role) {

    console.log("USER DATA > > " + name + " > > " + mob + " > > " + mail + " > > " + addr);

    console.log("USER LOC > > " + state + " > > " + dist + " > > " + subdist );

    document.getElementById("namee").value = name;
    document.getElementById("mobilee").value = mob;
    document.getElementById("emaile").value = mail;
    document.getElementById("addre").value = addr;

    $('#state-pickere option:selected').value = state;

    $('#district-pickere-buttonTitle').multiselect({
        buttonText: function(options, select) {
            return dist;
        }
    });

    $('#sub-district-pickere-buttonText').value = subdist;

}
```

**UPDATE**

```
$('#district-pickere').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: false,
        maxHeight: 300,
        nonSelectedText: dist
    });
```

The above code works during init. But How can I change the nonselected test from another function when a button is clicked ?

Comment: are you referring to the title of the select when the user has NOT selected any options? (plus the title when the user selected more options that could be visible?)

Comment: I am not referring to anything, am I?

Comment: What's the id of the select control? Is it pickere-buttonTitle or pickere?

Comment: Perhaps your `dist` is `undefined`?

Comment: pickere is the id of the control

Comment: @FrankFajardo I tried printing the dist value in console. it works there...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to programmatically select an option for the multiselect plugin , you need to call the method `$('#district-pickere').multiselect('select',['myvalue'])` where your value must be passed in an array

Please note that the multiselect will remember the previously selected options, so its good to deselect all values by calling

`$('#district-pickere').multiselect('deselectAll',false);`

and then as per documentation call `$('#district-pickere').multiselect('updateButtonText')`

So follow this order

1. `$('#district-pickere').multiselect('deselectAll',false);`
2. `$('#district-pickere').multiselect('select',['myvalue'])`
3. `$('#district-pickere').multiselect('updateButtonText')`

In case that your multiselect control has no values and you want to override the text that informs the user that he needs to select a value (or which values he has selected) you do this By overriding in config the buttonText property

```
$('#example-buttonText').multiselect({
      buttonText:function(options,select){
       if (options.length === 0) {
              return 'Please select something';
       }else if (options.length > 3) {
         return 'More than 3 options selected!';
       }else {
          var labels = [];
          options.each(function() {
          if ($(this).attr('label') !== undefined) {
             labels.push($(this).attr('label'));
           }else {
              labels.push($(this).html());
           }
         });
        return labels.join(', ') + '';
       }
      }
});
```

If you need to change only the text for no options selected you can do it with the init and setting the property nonSelectedText

```
$('#myselect').multiselect({
    nonSelectedText:'I have no selection'
 });
```

If you need to do it programmtically via a button click (#changeTitle is a button id) then you can call the `setOptions` with a new configuration and then call `rebuild` in order for the multiselect to rebuild with the new confirmation

```
$('#changeTitle').click(function(){

  $('#myselect').multiselect('setOptions',{nonSelectedText:'I have no options to select'});
  $('#myselect').multiselect('rebuild');
 });
```

Comment: Actually the picker has no values. It will be populated only after selecting the state picker is selected. Can we have show text without populating the options ?

Comment: I have updated the code, please also check codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdjGVV?editors=1111

Comment: Please check the update. I need to change the `nonSelectedText` in a function other than init ?

Comment: I have updated the code and please also check the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJBegb?editors=1111 for a live example

Comment: I need to deselect the options & show the text. check this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xaJMmP?editors=1111

Comment: You need to make a correction and put the attribute "multiple" in your select html element `<select id="myselect" multiple>`

Comment: I don't need multiple picker. I want to choose only one value from the picker.

Comment: Ok , but there is an issue like that, because when the select has single selection enabled, it will by default show as selected the first option. Thats why you see Cheese and the `nonSelectedText` is not working because for the control cheese value is already selected.